# pascal numbers in a triangle format

Tags: haskell

WIth the help of the members of this community, especially by Daniel I can mke the list of pascal triangles number. BUt Whenever i want to display the triangle as a triangle shape it gives error like: parse error on input 'import'. I expct some1 will cme forward to explain me this. the code is below:

```
    import Text.Printf

    pascal :: [[Integer]]
    pascal = iterate (\prev -> 1 : zipWith (+) prev (tail prev) ++ [1]) [1]

    prettyPascal :: Int -> IO ()
    prettyPascal n = mapM_ (\r -> printf "%*s\n" (div (longest + length r) 2) r) rows
    where rows = map (unwords . map show) $ take (n + 1) pascal
      longest = length $ last rows
```

Comment: That's strange. You should get a parse error on the line with the `where`, that must be indented farther than `prettyPascal`. And that's where I get a parse error. I'm not sure if you do that in your files, or if it's how you format your code here on Stack Overflow, but it is not a good idea to let the top level code start in a column that is not the first (too easy to mess up). Further, you would need a module declaration `module Whatever where`, without one, `module Main (main) where` is assumed, and compilation fails if there is no `main`.

Comment: where is not indented properly HERE. Will main be like this:                                                                              main :: IO ()
              main = prettyPascal 10

Comment: Yes, that could be the `main`. But if you add a module declaration, you can make the other definitions in that module available to other modules, so I'd still recommend doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary answer:

```
module PrettyPascal where  -- good practice, means you can combine it with other code
import Text.Printf

pascal :: [[Integer]]
pascal = iterate (\prev -> 1 : zipWith (+) prev (tail prev) ++ [1]) [1]
```

`where` must be further indented than the line before, and `longest` must line up with `rows`:

```
prettyPascal :: Int -> IO ()
prettyPascal n = mapM_ (\r -> printf "%*s\n" (div (longest + length r) 2) r) rows
 where rows = map (unwords . map show) $ take (n + 1) pascal
       longest = length $ last rows
```

You could do  `main = prettyPascal 10`, but you might prefer:

```
main = 
    putStrLn "How many rows of Pascal's triangle would you like to see?"
    >> readLn >>= prettyPascal
```

(If you're using ghci or Hugs, you don't need a `main`, you can just type `prettyPrint 10` at the prompt.)

Other points from discussion below:

- Haskell is case sensitive, so it has to be `prettyPascal`, not `PrettyPascal`.
- When you're using a type class (as in your other code), you need `Eq a =>` instead of `Eq a ->`
- Use copy-and-paste to avoid typing errors
- Save your functions in a file called something like `PrettyPascal.hs`.
- Then load your functions in ghci by typing `:l PrettyPascal`.
- Sometimes if you're not sure whether it's your compiler or your code, copy-and-paste to `codepad.org` for a second opinion. (You could also download and install the fast Hugs compiler which does Haskell 98 and multiparameter typeclasses, but not lots of ghc extensions.)

Comment: @SaugataBose That's strange. Which editor are you using, on what operating system? What compiler/interpreter are you using?

Comment: i am using ghci 6.12.3. this is the whole code i m giving the complier to compile:                                                            module prettyPascal where
import Text.Printf
pascal' = iterate (\prev -> 1 : zipWith (+) prev (tail prev) ++ [1]) [1]
prettyPascal n = mapM_ (\r -> printf "%*s\n" (div (longest + length r) 2) r) rows
        where rows = map (unwords . map show) $ take (n + 1) pascal'
               longest = length $ last rows

Comment: @SaugataBose Are you really sure that that's _all_ that's in the file? Which editor are you using, on what operating system? I'd only expect this sort of message if your file doesn't start with the word `module`.

Comment: the most intertestng thing i found that whenever i try to use any code using import it gets the same error on ghci 6.12.3

Comment: and the main thng is i cannot compile any code which has this import. i dnt understand whether i shoud use any code befre import or its da prblm of smethng else

Comment: suppose i fail to compile this code also:                                                               module Pm where
import Data.List
permutation::Eq a->[a]->[[a]]

permutation []=[[]]
permutation xs= [x:ys|x<-xs, ys<-permutation(delete x xs)]

Comment: You should put `module ModuleName where` at the start of the first line, and `import Other.Module` on the next line, at the start.

Comment: Can you try using another editor? Are you putting line breaks in?

Comment: the error exists                                                                    basics.hs:133:0: parse error on input `module'
Failed, modules loaded: none.                                                                module PrettyPascal where import Other.Module import Text.Printf... ... I CANT GET IT ANYWY.......IS THERE ANY WY TO SEND THE FULL CODE TO U?

Comment: @SaugataBose Haskell is case sensitive, so you can't put capital P at the front of `prettyPascal`. Why not copy and paste rather than retyping?

Comment: i just copy-pste ur code: http://codepad.org/ReC7v5rt.......it still shows da error

Comment: @SaugataBose OK we're getting somewhere now. We just need to add `main = prettyPascal 10`, or the other main.

Comment: @SaugataBose Oh, OK, codepad's configured to use `Main.main`, so edit `module PrettyPascal where` to say `module Main where`

Comment: Excellent. Fantbullous. atlast i got a solutiion and most important is that I learn few technique. thanx a lot. NOw i have to solve the 2nd one: the permutation one which showed same prblm

Comment: BUt whts wrong with ghci. it still shows error there: parse error on input 'import'

Comment: @SaugataBose Did you copy and paste? I'll check at my end.

Comment: i just made copy-paste and the similar type of problem related with Main is shown for my 2nd problem of permutation. what are the critical points using module??? strange

Comment: @SaugataBose You'll need to comment out the other module, and you need to write `Eq a =>` not `Eq a ->`. Oh, and `import Other.Module` was an example, so needs to go.

Comment: For which one u r referrng this code? I copied pste the pascl triangle code in ghci and it showed me the error: parse error on input 'module'.

Comment: @SaugataBose Oh - are you pasting straight into ghci? It's not designed for that - you need to paste into a file called something like `PrettyPascal.hs` and then do `:l PrettyPascal` in ghci.

Comment: @SaugataBose Has that fixed the problem?

Comment: excellent, its done, Andrew,thnx. and i solvd the permutation one also......its tremendous. its all my pleasure to have such a mentor like you.

Comment: ANd i dont need to put main within code in ghci compiler. I Just check this

Comment: @SaugataBose Now you'll be able to keep different bits of code in separate files, and just `:l` them when you need them. There's no stopping you now!